# Return unique difference between dict and dataframe records

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have data like the image_attr_df data below.  I want to compare a dict of values to a specified list of records from the dataframe, and return a dict with column and value that is unique to original dict.

So in this example I'm comparing the "purch" dict to the records with image_id = [1615, 1561].  I would like to have my code return:

```
{('Sleeve', 'Long sleeves')}
```

Right now it's returning the columns and values that are different for each record.  Does anyone know how I can filter that final dict to just return a dict with just the unique columns and values, (like my example above?)

`img_attr_df`:

```
   image_id Neckline         Sleeve Skin_exposure
0       619  V-shape   Long sleeves  Low exposure
1      1615  V-shape  Short sleeves  Low exposure
2      1561    Round  Short sleeves  Low exposure
```

`purch`:

```
   image_id Neckline        Sleeve Skin_exposure
0       619  V-shape  Long sleeves  Low exposure
```

Code:

```
def diff_attributes(df_na,dataset,To_compare):
    compared=[]

    for i in To_compare:
        compared.append(set(dataset.loc[:,input_df.columns!='image_id'].to_dict(orient ='records')[0].items())-set(df_na[df_na['image_id']==i].loc[:,input_df.columns!='image_id'].to_dict(orient ='records')[0].items()))

    return compared

input_df=img_attr_df[['image_id','Neckline','Sleeve','Skin_exposure']]
comp_list=[1615,1561]

diff_attributes(input_df,purch,comp_list)
```

Output:

```
[{('Sleeve', 'Long sleeves')},
 {('Neckline', 'V-shape'), ('Sleeve', 'Long sleeves')}]
```

Desired output:

```
{('Sleeve', 'Long sleeves')}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I slightly change your function using `isin`

```
def diff_attributes(df_na,dataset,To_compare):
    compared=[]
    for i in dataset.columns[1:]:
        if ~dataset[i].isin(df_na.loc[df_na['image_id'].isin(To_compare),i]).any():
            compared.append((i,dataset[i][0]))
    return compared
input_df=df[['image_id','Neckline','Sleeve','Skin_exposure']]
comp_list=[1615,1561]
diff_attributes(input_df,purch,comp_list)
Out[142]: [('Sleeve', 'Longsleeves')]
```

Comment: @user3476463 yw :-) happy coding